# Strange string conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, variables, reactjs

In some libs I have seen something like this

```
 if ("development" !== 'production') {
        "development" !== 'production' ? warning(this instanceof Constructor, 'Something is calling a React component directly. Use a factory or ' + 'JSX instead. See: '') : void 0;
      }
```

Example from React.js

So how use string as variable like this? Is there any trick or JS hidden feature?

Comment: OP said example from React.js and I checked it is in the React.js codebase.

Comment: @maioman React,js 15.3.2 lines 719,739,748 (134 expression total)

Comment: Pretty sure OP asking why such code would even exist when `if ("development" !== 'production')` should always be true. And then it is followed by a `"development" !== 'production' ?` which does the same thing.

Comment: @GillesC I saw that, it's a build related issue..

Comment: I think the ternary operator and the if conditions shown here are redundant. You either use the if statement or the ternary operator, no need for both checking the same thing (i.e. "development" !== 'production').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see looks odd because the file you are looking at is the result of a build process being applied to a source file that started like this:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
```

The source can be built in "production" or "development" mode, affecting the warnings that are shown to the user.

Comment: Make sense but the code sample posted by OP does highlight well how ugly the code generated is.

Comment: @GillesC so why not use if(true) if(1) in cases like this?

Comment: Or just add script rows if it is true without if

Comment: Exactly. My point exactly. I do not understand myself why would be the ppoint to generate such code. If anything it will impact on performance. But it seemed to be the way of JS coding nowadays. Clean code base (ES6, Typescript) and ugly generated/unoptimized code for production. Progress hey :)

Comment: @GillesC in "production" mode, the JS compiler will skip the whole block, so this will have a negligible impact on compile time and zero impact on execution time. Also, it is quite common to use a tool that does dead code elimination as part of the build process, so this block would be removed at that point. That said, it looks as though the combination of the `if` and the ternary is completely redundant in this case...

Answer (score 4):

Comparisons like these aren't likely written as JavaScript code in their originating file- if you see code like this, it is because one of the strings was not hard-coded in the page source code - rather, the page was rendered in the back-end server, and some JavaScript strings were originally variables in the back-end side of the application.

It is not a good practice to use templated JavaScript code - but just as any back-end application can render HTML elements at page-serving time, so it can render pieces of JavaScript code.

What happens here is that one side of that comparison was coded something like `"{{environment}}"` on the page template.  When the back-end engine serves that page to the browser, the content with this special markup (like, whatever is between `{{` and `}}` - is replaced by server-side variables - on the browser, all you get are static strings - that compare differently, of course.

(That said - this is what happens if you find things like dthis coded in rendered web-pages in the wild - specific JavaScript code-bases might have code like this from ... " artifacts deriving from human interaction in the development process"  :-)  )

Comment: I am sure it is JS file, and I say alsa have seen other examples , currently I can provide this one

Comment: I don't think your opening statement "This is not JavaScript code" is accurate or helpful. It is quite obviously JavaScript code (and valid code at that). The code used to *generate* that JavaScript code could be any language at all (including JavaScript).

Comment: So, as stated in the other answer - it is likely a  JS file   generated in some part of the build process that for some reason got versioned.

Comment: @Mike - thanks - I rephrased that to correctly reflect what is actually going on.